# How to add a table in absolute position at the beginning of the page using iTextSharp?

Tags: c#, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

I have a class named **PdfHeaderFooter** that extends **PdfPageEventHelper** class.

In this class I have implemented the **OnEndPage()** method in this way. How you can see this method create the **header** and the **footer** of each pages of the document.

Now I have to add the **PdfPTable tabHead** in absolute position at the beginning of the page.

What can I have to do? I am going crazy trying to do it

```
    // write on end of each page
    public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
    {
        base.OnEndPage(writer, document);

        // HEADER:
        PdfPTable tabHead = new PdfPTable(3);
        tabHead.SetWidths(new int[] { 165, 205, 125 });


        //tabHead.TotalWidth = 460F;
        tabHead.TotalWidth = document.Right - document.Left;        // TotalWidth = 495
        tabHead.WidthPercentage = 98;


        PdfPCell cell1 = new PdfPCell(iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(folderImages + "logoEarlyWarning.png"), true) { Border = PdfPCell.BOTTOM_BORDER };
        tabHead.AddCell(cell1);
        //tabHead.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("CELL 1:")) { Border = PdfPCell.BOTTOM_BORDER, Padding = 5, MinimumHeight = 50, PaddingTop = 15, });

        tabHead.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("")) { Border = PdfPCell.BOTTOM_BORDER, Padding = 5, MinimumHeight = 50, PaddingTop = 15 });

        if (_sourceId == "NVD")
        {
            iTextSharp.text.Image logo = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(folderImages + "nvdLogo.png");
            logo.ScalePercent(48f);
            //PdfPCell cell3 = new PdfPCell(iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(folderImages + "nvdLogo.png"), true) { Border = PdfPCell.BOTTOM_BORDER, PaddingBottom = 25 };
            PdfPCell cell3 = new PdfPCell(logo) { Border = PdfPCell.BOTTOM_BORDER, PaddingLeft = 50 };
            tabHead.AddCell(cell3);
        }
        else if (_sourceId == "DeepSight")
        {
            PdfPCell cell3 = new PdfPCell(iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(folderImages + "DSLogo.jpg"), true) { Border = PdfPCell.BOTTOM_BORDER };
            tabHead.AddCell(cell3);
        }
        //tabHead.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("CELL 3:")) { Border = PdfPCell.BOTTOM_BORDER, Padding = 5, MinimumHeight = 50, PaddingTop = 15 });


        tabHead.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, document.Left, document.Top, writer.DirectContent);

        float headerHeight = tabHead.CalculateHeights();


        // FOOTER:
        int pageN = writer.PageNumber;      // numero della pagina corrente OK
        String text = "Page " + pageN + " of ";
        float len = bf.GetWidthPoint(text, 8);

        Rectangle pageSize = document.PageSize;

        cb.SetRGBColorFill(100, 100, 100);

        cb.BeginText();
        cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, 8);
        cb.SetTextMatrix(pageSize.GetLeft(40), pageSize.GetBottom(30));
        cb.ShowText(text);
        cb.EndText();

        cb.AddTemplate(template, pageSize.GetLeft(40) + len, pageSize.GetBottom(30));

        cb.BeginText();
        cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, 8);
        cb.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_RIGHT,
            "Printed On " + PrintTime,
            pageSize.GetRight(40),
            pageSize.GetBottom(30), 0);
        cb.EndText();

    }
```

Tnx

Comment: I'm not really clear on what your specific question is. Does the above code not work? You are using `WriteSelectedRows` which is how you would absolutely position a table, is that not working as expected?

Comment: so my tabHead table is already positioned absolute at the beginning pf the page?

Answer (score 0):

This question has already been answered here: [How to handle the case in wich an iText\iTextSharp table is splitted in two pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24080787/how-to-handle-the-case-in-wich-an-itext-itextsharp-table-is-splitted-in-two-page)

You are adding the header at the beginning of the page, taking into account the margin. You want to add the table inside the margin. hence you need to add the height of the table to the Y-coordinate of the upper margin.

For instance: if the height of the table is `h`, then you need:

```
tabHead.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, document.Left, document.Top + h, writer.DirectContent);
```

What's the point in asking questions if you don't read people's answers? You're still generating a bloated PDF file! Fix that!